# BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, service-broker

I experienced an issue with the SQL Server service broker. If I quickly run several times a the script below.

```
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @DBHandle
FROM SERVICE A
TO SERVICE N'B'
ON CONTRACT CommandExec
WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF
```

Sometimes @DBHandle has value null. I noticed it because the SEND ON CONVERSATION fails with "The conversation handle is missing. Specify a conversation handle".

Are there any structural limits on SQL Server? I expected an error, why a null value is returned?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: There are no limitations I'm aware of. I suspect the conversation was ended before the `SEND`, perhaps by a cleanup process.

Comment: I don't think so. I tried adding a SEND immediately after the BEGIN DIALOG and sometimes it fails at the same way

Comment: Btw, you don’t need to use `SEND` to notice the handle is invalid. You can explicitly check it for NULL and raise error.

Comment: Ok, but the question is: why the BEGIN DIALOG returns null? What is the issue?